# Libgdx executable Jar file not opening

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, libgdx

I made a game using libgdx and now I'm trying to make an executable jar file, so what I did is go to project structure -> artifacts -> jar -> from module to dependencies -> then select desktop module and DesktopLauncher as main class, then build artifact. The problem is that when I try to open the jar file nothing happens, it doesn't open. I'm pretty sure that my java is not the issue because I am able to open other jar files, or maybe my way of creating the jar file is wrong?

Comment: it says unable to access jar file

Comment: I think you should try to build jar with gradle.